# Angular 8 ionic 4 proxy not working, returnin 404

Tags: angular, proxy, ionic4

I am building a jwt auth app, and for solving cors error, I am using a proxy but I'm getting an error:

> zone-evergreen.js:2952 POST http://localhost:4200/api/session/login 404 (Not Found)

I need to send this to : http://my-server:port/api/session/login.

my proxy.config.js

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http:/my-server:port/api/auth/login",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite": {
            "/api": "http://my-server:port/api"
        }
    }
}
```

angular.json:

```
"serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "app:build",
                        "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
                    },
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: no sorry, i didn't.

Comment: Ok, In my case back end services wasn't up properly. Once I restarted it started working.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Ionic CLI.